# How to remove blank 2D list rows?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am trying to remove blank elements/rows from a 2D list in python.

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
 [], [], [], [], [], [], 
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

sorry if this is simple but I have never had this problem in matlab and am stumped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with `None` will remove empty values for you:

```
lst = filter(None, lst)
```

Alternatively you could use a list comprehension for the same result:

```
lst = [nested for nested in lst if nested]
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
>>> filter(None, lst)
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
>>> [nested for nested in lst if nested]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Suppose the outer list is named `list`, then you can remove inner empty list as follows:

```
list = [['61710480', '385950.51', '6526136.92', '59.369\n'], 
      [], [], [], [], [], [], 
      ['61710487', '381808.8', '6519876.8', '53.292\n'], 
      ['61710488', '381808.8', '6519876.8', '53.183\n']]

list = [l for l in list if len(l)>0]
```

Comment: I said "suppose". However it works also using "list". Try on console! You penalized me on the base of elegant or non elegant way to write code while code works right.

Comment: You were downvoted because you used bad practices; the code may *work* but actually using these techniques as is, is not a good idea.